# How can i execute migrations from localhost cli into a docker container

Tags: node.js, postgresql, docker, docker-compose, typeorm

I'm working on a project using Docker and Docker Compose. Currently, I have two containers: one for the PostgreSQL server and the other for the application. I'm using TypeORM as an ORM, and I'm trying to run migrations from my CLI. However, the database is configured to connect with the Docker container. As a result, when I try to run the migration using TypeORM CLI, it doesn't find the host because it doesn't exist on my local machine. Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can proceed?

I'm expecting a suggestion or a better way to preceed

Answer (score 1):

Each docker container is exposed to your local network on a specific port which you include when you start your container. For example if you specify ports in your docker-compose file like so:

```yaml
ports:
  - '5432:9000'
```

This will expose whatever is inside of the container on port `5432` (which should be your db server) to port `9000` of your localhost (make sure that this port is not occupied by any other application, for example your own local PostgreSQL server).

So pick a port on your local network, specify it in the docker-compose file, restart it and see if it's really exposed by using a client for your database (pgAdmin for example).

Now you only need to specify a different options for TypeORM CLI with credentials to access db server that is in Docker container for when you want to run your migrations inside of it. You can do this by providing a different ormconfig:

```
typeorm migration:run -d docker-ormconfig.json
```